# Downside with moving pagefile to different drive

Tags: windows-server-2003, partition, disk-space-utilization, raid10, pagefile

I've been tasked with managing an old Windows 2003 server which will be decommissioned later this year. I just need to keep the server up and running long enough.

The space on the server is running low. I've cleaned out the most that I can and also compressed some old files, but space is still low on C:

Look like I am able to move the pagefile over to D:\ which has plenty of space. Both C: and D: are partitioned of the same physical drive (RAID-10), so I'm hoping the performace will be (around) the same. I'm not looking to increase speed, but hoping that it would not cause any significant slowness.

Does anyone see any issues I might encounter moving the pagefile over to D:?

Answer (score 2):

No. I can't think of any technical reason why there would be a downside to moving the pagefile location to another drive of sufficient size in your situation. In fact we do this for all of our servers to improve deduplication rates.

Additionally, I have found that if you are running up against disk space limitations that [WinDirStat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=https://windirstat.info/&ei=lMsSU621PIntoATP_4GoDg&usg=AFQjCNEgXPuzzomSWnSlrgX1Zp85DT-eFQ&bvm=bv.62286460,d.cGU) is useful in identifying where your storage is used.